# What is the "Browser File" in Visual Studio 2008 and why may we need it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

While adding a new file in VS 2008 website, I found something called "Browser File". Does anyone know what is this, how to use and when to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These .browser files are [Browser Definition File Schemas (browsers Element)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122(v=vs.100).aspx) (from the MSDN documentation):

> Browser definition files contain
>   definitions for individual browsers.
>   At run time, ASP.NET uses the
>   information in the request header to
>   determine what type of browser has
>   made the request. Then ASP.NET uses
>   .browser files to determine the
>   capabilities of the browser, and how
>   to render markup to that browser.
>
> This
>   is useful to Web developers who want
>   to create applications that can be
>   viewed on mobile devices, making use
>   of control adapters that adapt the
>   behavior of an ASP.NET Web server
>   control depending on the type of
>   device. For more information, see the
>   links in the See Also section.

Answer (score 3):

The browser file defines the capabilities of a certain browser, can be used to change what markup that is transmitted to the client.

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's also good to know that this file is still being updated as new mobile devices come out.  You can get the latest version here: http://mdbf.codeplex.com/.